# Storied ways to boost a character's ability scores (Pathfinder)

Tags: pathfinder-1e, gm-techniques, new-players

So this is my first time acting as a GM for a campaign (taking over for a friend). Improperly built characters at the start of their campaign has lead to 2/5 character having very high stats. Because of this I've raised the CR of monsters the party goes up against in combat.

The reason it has become a problem is that one of the PCs (a monk) has much lower stats, which results in them getting KOed in most fights. While the higher stat PC (a fighter) can basically walk through the fray unscathed.

My question is if anyone has creative ways to change the ability scores to even them out with as little metagaming and rerolling as possible?

Comment: This seems to be a request for idea generation, which is pretty open-ended and more suitable for [forums](//meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go).

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the main reasons that I dislike rolling for stats (I assume this is what happened). The easiest way to avoid this sort of problem in the future is to do a point buy system which will give everyone's character an equal opportunity to be powerful. This also provides a great deal of choice in the matter which is always great to have while making a character. As a player, the worst thing ever is to get crappy rolls that first day, and be stuck with them forever while your buddies were lucky that first day and benefit forever.

**Retcon** - The easiest is just to talk with the players, figure out the stat differences with the highest and lowest characters, and just give the lowest characters points they can spend to 'bring their characters up to speed' as it were. Avoid nerfing powerful characters, as this brings about resentment.

**Items** - Next, you could throw out some items that would be useful for that character. Imagine a belt of dex +4 for the monk, and what that would do for survivability. Or even monk's robes (expensive). The downside to this is that eventually, the fighter will get items like this, bringing back the problem again. You might even consider the various tomes that increase stats, but those can be expensive as well, plus your good characters will want those as well.

**In-Game Events** - Imagine the group walks into a temple and finds some altar of power. Those who touch the altar get a certain permanent benefit. You would probably take this opportunity to give the less powerful characters more powerful benefits (although you should give everyone something, else you get player resentment).

Comment: Thanks for the input, I am new to the site and wasn't sure exactly where to post this question.  BaseHobo, thanks for the quick answer, definitely the kinds of things I was looking for. And yes it was rolled, most of the players had never played before so we figured that would be a good way to have it somewhat equal... We were very mistaken.  I do like that alter idea, might work something similar into one of the next adventures.